# Can cheap HDMI cables really give a poorer image?

Tags: hdmi, cable

I understand it is a digital signal. However, I bought two very cheap cables as spares. My current cable (Amazon basics) seems to be giving me issues (random signal loss, reproduced by wiggling the plug). One of my spares does not have this issue. However, the image is poor. It seems muddy and aliased and blocky. I thought my HDTV, which I'm using as a monitor, had automatically set into a different image mode (you know, movie, dynamic, blah blah) but nope, it was in standard mode. Awful image. I plugged the Amazon cable back in and it looks perfect.

I'm confused as the poorer image seems to go against everything I understood.

Comment: The signal is digital. A packet with data arrives intact **or** it does not arrive in tact. If it gets corrupted or lost the wrong data is not used. It is either dropped/ignored, or a resent is requested.

If that happens a lot and not all data arrives in time then you may get similar problems.

*May*. I am very much NOT an expert on HDMI.

Comment: Do different leads have different capabilities I.e are older leads not wired to support the same feature as modern leads? It is frustrating as it makes no sense to me how the image would look so much worse.

Comment: From my personal tests and everything I do at work I have not seen any difference between the $2 cables purchased from monoprice and $50+ monster cables.  Read through the comments [here](http://lifehacker.com/5506219/why-you-should-never-pay-more-than-10-for-hdmi-cables) to find out more about what affects a digitial signal in general and why it's unlikely your hdmi cable will be affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for a cheap HDMI cable to produce a poor image, as you are seeing.

Effectively, your cable is "dodgy", and is distorting the "digital" signal so much that it is corrupting the bits on the way through.   This is much like a "marginal" signal for digital TV - you still get a picture, but it freezes and is quite blocky because parts of the digital stream are missing and the decoder is trying to cope with it

In your case, I wonder if just one of the connections on your cable is not connected.  I had a similar problem with a DVI-HDMI cable, which gave me a signal, but a lot of static/lines unless I wiggled the cable and got it just right.

The meme that there is no difference between a cheap expensive digital cable is fairly accurate, but not 100%. If the cable can get all the bits across it without corruption, the result of the cables is identical.

Comment: The image is usable- i mean, I can see what is going on with no blocking up like a poor digital tv signal. It is that the overall image itself looks like it is blockier, and as if the colours have less range. Brighter colours were too washed out and the darker colours were muddied together. It annoys me that this was the case!

Comment: These cakes were £1 each delivered by the way. As I was adamant that a cable is a cable especially if it is providing a digital signal, I didn't think it would matter!

Comment: As davidgo said, the quality difference is between a cheap cable and a normal cable, you get 0% improvement for going beyond that if all the bit's are getting through.

Answer (score 2):

HDMI is a standard- so any cables which conform to this standard should work fine.

The only way a cheap HDMI cable is going to cause problems is if it's *sub* standard- but I've never come across one that bad before.

I've found no difference between $7 HDMI cables from eBay, and $70 brand cables with gold-plated connectors.

Due to the nature of the digital signal- the picture either tends to either be "perfect", or suffer from obvious macroblocking or have very obvious interferences lines through it. Differences are not subtle- and if you're having to look closely to notice a difference, you're probably not noticing problems caused by your cheap HDMI cable.

I've even connected 3 "cheap" HDMI leads end to end to connect a laptop to a TV the other side of a living room, and it works as well as when a short run of expensive HDMI cable is used.

So, in other words: don't get sucked in by the marketing guys who try to make you feel you need to pay a lot for good quality.

Comment: The difference between the two is quite stark sadly and this annoys me!

Comment: Fun fact: Gold-plated connectors probably make things slightly *worse* than normal connectors. If you can avoid those then do so.

Comment: Good point. I just checked it out- and gold is a slightly *worse* conductor than copper. Hilarious. I guess they just use it because it looks cooler on a box and they can argue it is less likely to corrode. I can honestly say I've never seen any corrosion on a copper connector of any kind.

Comment: I think they are all gold now really. If not gold, a silver colour, and I find with headphones that the silver colour wears and the gold does not?

Comment: It varies- connectors in general use various metals: gold, copper, platinum, rhodium, tin. BNC connectors apparently use zinc-plating. Copper has the best conductivity, gold is the least reactive, but one of the most expensive and not the best conductor. Sadly- for home electronics most cables with gold connectors have it so they can brag about it on the side of the box (attempting to justify a higher price), rather than any significant technical benefit.

Answer (score 2):

"Cheap" isn't really an indicator of anything.  As Austin ''Danger'' Powers explained, there's a standard, well actually a series of standards, and to legally bear the HDMI logo, the cable has to comply with one of the standards.  It's possible that some shady manufacturers are selling cheap cables by saving manufacturing costs and making non-compliant cables.  That would be more a question of a misleading sales practice through false use of the HDMI logo on the product.  Causing signal loss by wiggling the plug on a new cable, when similar action doesn't affect other cables, would suggest some shoddy manufacturing, though.

Aside from the loose plug issue, the problem is more likely the use of an HDMI cable that meets a standard too low for the application.  At the current time, there have been something like nine versions of the HDMI spec, with successive versions sometimes requiring a more sophisticated cable to support the signals.  mr.spuratic's answer mentions "Standard" and "High Speed cables".  Since that time "Premium" and "Ultra High Speed" have been added to the list (and there are actually some other categories for other cable uses).

Those cable categories define construction that supports the requirements for different levels (versions) of the HDMI standard.  The HDMI standard has evolved to support more and more demanding applications.  If the original cable design was adequate for the requirements of the later standards, there would have been no need for the later cable designs.  Those cable categories aren't marketing terms to sell fancier-looking cables with useless features at higher prices, they are actually different designs needed to support the demands of the usage made possible by the later spec.

Manufacturers are still free to sell cables that meet only early versions of the HDMI spec (Standard cable), and there are still applications for which those cables are fine.  But if you have a more demanding requirement, you will get the kinds of crappy performance described in this thread if you don't use a cable designed to support it.  In terms of "cheap cable", each successive "level" of cable is going to be more expensive to manufacture (and will have a price marked up to what the market will bear), so a Standard cable will be "cheap" compared to a High Speed or Premium cable.

Some of the capabilities of the successive HDMI specs are summarized in these tables (courtesy of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI)):

Standard Video (refers to the video, not the cable):

[image]

Feature Support:

[image]

The Wikipedia article summarizes the cables that support the different levels of requirements.  The general use ones:

- Standard HDMI Cable – up to 1080i and 720p
- High Speed HDMI Cable – 1080p, 4K 30 Hz, 3D and deep color
- Premium High Speed HDMI Cable - 18 Gbit/s HDMI 2.0 bandwidth
- Ultra High Speed HDMI Cable (48G Cable) – 4K, 5K, 8K and 10K at 120 Hz (48 Gbit/s HDMI 2.1 bandwidth)

[HDMI's website](https://www.hdmi.org/consumer/finding_right_cable.aspx) describes them in a little more detail.  I'll excerpt the general use cables:

**Standard HDMI Cable**
The Standard HDMI cable is designed to handle most home applications, and is tested to reliably transmit 1080i or 720p video – the HD resolutions that are commonly associated with cable and satellite television, digital broadcast HD, and upscaling DVD players.

**High Speed HDMI Cable**
The High Speed HDMI cable is designed and tested to handle video resolutions of 1080p and beyond, including advanced display technologies such as 4K, 3D, and Deep Color. If you are using any of these technologies, or if you are connecting your 1080p display to a 1080p content source, such as a Blu-ray Disc player, this is the recommended cable.

**Premium High Speed HDMI Cable and Premium High Speed HDMI Cable with Ethernet**
are special certification designations for High Speed HDMI Cables that have been designed and certified for ultra-reliable performance for 4K/UltraHD including advanced features such as 4K60, HDR, expanded color spaces including BT.2020, and 4:4:4 chroma sampling. They have low EMI and are identified by HDMI Licensing Administrator’s Premium HDMI Cable Certification Label for authentication verification.

**Ultra High Speed HDMI Cable**
ensures ultra high-bandwidth dependent features are delivered including uncompressed 8K video with HDR. It supports up to 48Gbps bandwidth and features exceptionally low EMI (electro-magnetic interference) which reduces interference with nearby wireless devices. The cable also supports the HDMI Ethernet channel. It is backwards compatible and can be used with the existing installed base of HDMI devices.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the cheap cable is category 1 ("standard") suitable for 720p/1080i, or category 2 ("high speed"), required for 1080p. There's also a small chance there's a problem on the DDC connection which prevents proper identification of the display.

See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906663.

Comment: The link is dead and I couldn't find any archived copies.